# Robocopy One-Way Sync

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, robocopy

I think my command is wrong.

I only want to do a oneway sync from `c:\SmarterMail\Domains` tp `\\My.IP.Add.Ress\C$\SmarterMail\Domains`

My current command is this:

```
robocopy /E /S /MIR /Z /W:1 /R:1 /MIR \\My.IP.Add.Ress\C$\SmarterMail\Domains C:\SmarterMail\Domains
```

But... the more I read, it looks like this may be a two-way mirroring?   What command do I need just to do the one-way sync?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) the syntax is as follows:

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]] [<Options>]
```

There's a few oddities with your script:

1. /S copies subdirectories (but not empty ones) /E copies subdirectories including empty ones.  /E implies /S so you can drop the /S
2. However /Mir is described thusly "Mirrors a directory tree (equivalent to /e plus /purge)" So you can drop both the /E and the /S
3. You've included the /Mir option twice?  Unnecessary
4. **Main Issue** - you've got the source and destination the wrong way round...

So the command should be

```
robocopy /MIR /Z /W:1 /R:1 C:\SmarterMail\Domains \\My.IP.Add.Ress\C$\SmarterMail\Domains
```